# Which is the correct git repo for building wso2is from source?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am new to wso2, attempting to evaluate the platform. I have cloned both of the following repos to build wso2is. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity, this one does not produce a single zip distributable, not sure what I am missing to obtain a single file. If someone could tell me what I need to build this project into a single distribution, much appreciated. Next I tried https://github.com/wso2/product-is, which produces a single ditriibutable but it does not appear to be stable as there are numerous errors and the code does not work. Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There haven't been any IS releases done from the Git repo yet. So that is not stable yet. If you want to build the latest IS, use the SVN codebase chunk-11. (http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/product-releases/chunk-11/)

You can find which chunk to build by referring to [WSO2 release matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/).